# Is there any way I can load a image in to text file in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have a Image and i want to upload this image in a text file.is there any way I can do it using Delphi. Consider the image is a Barcode image and i want this image to be there at a particular location in the text file. This text file will be then uploded to report viewer where it will be printed in a report format.

Comment: It is impossible to understand the question.

Comment: Text files contain text, not images. Can you please clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you give an example of similar functionality in a different application?

Comment: I have a image(Ex: consider the image is a Barcode image) .I want this image to be pasted in the Text file. Is it possible to pasta a image in a text file?

Comment: maybe you are talking about ascii art?

Comment: Componentimage.savetofile('myfilename.ext')?

Comment: @Sutherson, I'm voting to close because this is not a real question. You can't save an image to a text file, because it would no longer be a text file if it contained images! I actually believe you're confusing the term "Text" file for something else, that's why I asked for a real example. So we can then tell you: 'Yeah, but that's NOT a text file'

Comment: @sutherson can you give more information about the "report viewer"?

Comment: It's possible to put an image into a Rich Text Format file. There are Delphi components that can help you do this.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, Shawn Chin, Ken White, jachguate, David Heffernan:  Was I the only one to (possibly) understand the question? You can embed any binary content into a true text file. MIME is doing it for our emails. I should not have closed this question, IMHO.

Comment: @A.Bouchez I'm not sure anyone understand the question, even if you think you did, the OP doesn't help at all, because a bit of clarification is all we need.  The question can be re-opened, but it needs a edit and more detail, for example is the mentioned report viewer capable to handle base64 encoded data, the OP wants to print the base64 encoding or the source image?.  As for now, I think it is better closed, because it is really hard to tell what is being asked here.

Comment: @jachguate Looks like he liked my answer. I've perhaps found out the purpose of its question. There are no bad questions, only silly answers. And sometimes you can guess the real question from the given answer. Like in real life... and in reverse-engineering... :)

Comment: @A.Bouchez what OP express in comments is a hope... my opinion is s/he can come and clarify, perhaps accept your answer... I'll vote to reopen in that case... but, my friend, until now this looks like a waste of time to all of us, specially to you that takes the time to answer this unclear question.

Comment: @A.Bouchez, take a look at the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313639/is-there-any-way-i-can-load-a-image-in-to-text-file-in-delphi) from this user...

Comment: @A.Bouchez this is the [correct link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325944/can-a-text-file-have-an-image) to the new question.

Answer (score 1):

If the 'text file' is just an exchange format, you could encode the picture as hexadecimal or as Base64 encoding (which will uses less space).

You've got BinToHex and HexToBin functions in Classes unit.

For instance:

```
function SaveAsText(Bmp: TBitmap): AnsiString;
var MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Bmp.SaveToStream(MS);
    SetLength(result,MS.Size*2);
    BinToHex(MS.Memory,pointer(result),MS.Size);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure LoadFromText(Bmp: TBitmap; const Text: AnsiString);
var MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    MS.Size := length(Text) shr 1;
    HexToBin(pointer(Text),MS.Memory,MS.Size);
    Bmp.LoadFromStream(MS);
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This is the method used e.g. by the MIME format to attach a binary file to an email (using Base64 encoding). An email is just some text. You may have to add some delimiters before and after the hexa/base64 text, just as MIME, to mark that this is some data, not text.

Comment: Hope this conversion will help me ..